# How to set a custom attribute value equal to a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-selectors

Here is my jquery:

```
if ($('div[data-sort= 23 ]').length > 0) {
    $('div[data-sort= 23 ]').after(newdiv); 
}
```

If I want to set the number 23 equal to n this is what I've done:

```
n = 23;
    if ($('div[data-sort= n ]').length > 0) {
        $('div[data-sort= n ]').after(newdiv);  
    }
```

But this doesn't work. Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var n = 23;
if ($('div[data-sort=' + n + ']').length > 0) {
    $('div[data-sort=' + n + ']').after(newdiv);  
}
```

You need to make your variable part of the string; in this new code the number `23` is concatenated into the string so the selector for jQuery will work. To see what jQuery receives as the selector you could run this:

```
var n = 23;
alert($('div[data-sort=' + n + ']').selector);
```

You should see "div[data-sort=23]".